# Поиск по пользователю в команде find

Tags: bash, shell, find

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста. Вот что я сварганил:

```
find /home/zadacha -type f -name '[0-3].[0-9].[0-0][4-5].2019' -user 'jboss' -fprint list.log sed -e '/^\//i\\' list.log
```

Получается файл `list.log`.  И там 2 наименования через пустую строку все как надо все красиво.  Но как сюда вставить еще поиск по группе?

Условие `jboss:br4j`, то есть по пользователю `jboss` все обрабатывается а по группе нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду группы пользователей Unix, то:

```sh
$ find … -group "$GROUPNAME"
```